# Run this command **npm run build** directly on cpanel

Tags: symfony, npm, hosting, cpanel, shared

$ npm run build

> build
> encore production --progress

Running webpack ...

**92% sealing asset processing CssMinimizerPluginKilled**

i need help

i want to have that command running, the process is killed at ninety two (92%) i dont know why where as every thing seem to be okay

My package.json

"scripts": {
"dev-server": "encore dev-server",
"dev": "encore dev",
"watch": "encore dev --watch",
"build": "encore production --progress",
},